# Jquery tablesorter plugin to sort format: 16-Jan-2010

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery Tablesorter and I have a problem sorting tables with date values of format: 16-Jan-2010

How do I make them sort properly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should write your own parser. for [jQuery Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html). Try converting the date to a format that does sort (example, YYMMDD will sort correctly as strings :))